# Django 3 OperationalError: no such table 'web_user'

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-authentication

I want to have 2 types of users in my Django app, so I [followed this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html) and ran

```
python manage.py makemigrations web
python manage.py migrate
```

('web' is the name of my app)

Now I want to access the `admin` part of the site, automatically added by django at `localhost:PORT/admin`. When I try to access that page, this error shows:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: web_user
```

Here's my `models.py`:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

from web import constants


class User(AbstractUser):
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (constants.USER_TYPE_CLEANER, 'cleaner'),
        (constants.USER_TYPE_CONTRACTOR, 'contractor'),
    )

    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)

    # extra fields
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField('date_of_birth')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

and set this in `settings.py`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'web.apps.WebConfig',
]

# Authentication
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'web.User'
```

How can I enable django's admin site? It's very useful for creating demo data.

Comment: have added 'web' in installed apps?

Comment: Did you add your app (web) in INSTALLED_APPS list (inside settings.py file)?

Comment: I have, see updated question

Comment: It's quite strange how you add the app to the `INSTALLED_APPS`, you can put just `web`, isn't?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that before running makemigrations and migrate, add your app name in `INSTALLED_APPS` in project settings

Comment: delete previous migrated files, db and again create superuser

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @bmons , the answer was to delete database `db.sqlite3`, migration files, and create a new user. Note that the extra fields **must** be nullable, otherwise creating a superuser will fail.